# What is the significance that Israel gave Joseph a robe of פַּסִּֽים?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 37:3

Berean Study Bible

> Now Israel loved Joseph more than his other sons, because Joseph had been born to him in his old age; so he made him a robe of **many colors**.

of many colors.
פַּסִּֽים׃ (pas·sîm)
Noun - masculine plural
Strong's 6446: Flat (of the hand or foot)

What is the significance that the robe is multi-colored?

Christian Standard Bible

> Now Israel loved Joseph more than his other sons because Joseph was a son born to him in his old age, and he made a **long-sleeved** robe for him.

What is the significance that the robe is long-sleeved?

Comment: Because he was the firstborn of Rachel who he loved. Tanakh says he was born in his old age. 1. He expressed his love by making a coat for him with many colors. 2. These are said to be fine wool to express how special Joseph was to him.. 3. There are some writings that Jacob knew that Jospeph will go through many trials like the colors in his coat.

Comment: What about the long-sleeved? Expand it into an answer. I usually +1 just for the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of this word פַס (pas) is debated and has been variously translated.  In short, the exact translated is uncertain.  However, what is certain is the STYLE rather than the colour because it was the sort of coat word by the prince or princess as per 2 Sam 13:18, 19.

Thus, the special coat or either many colours or long sleeves, etc, was significant precisely because it sent a clear message that the young Joseph was:

- valued above all the other brothers
- would become the main inheritor of the father property

Such a display of biased love must have been galling to the other brothers.  Note the comments of Ellicott -

> **A coat of many colours**.—Two explanations are given of this phrase; the first, that it was a long garment with sleeves or fringes; the
> other, that it was composed of patchwork of various colours. The
> latter is the more probable interpretation; for from the tomb at
> Beni-Hassan we learn that such dresses were worn in Palestine, as a
> train of captive Jebusites is represented upon it clad in rich robes,
> the patterns of which seem to have been produced by sewing together
> small pieces of different colours. So also in India beautiful dresses
> are made by sewing together strips of crimson, purple, and other
> colours. (Roberts’ Oriental Illustrations, p. 43.) Some have thought
> that Jacob by this dress marked out Joseph as the future head of the
> family, in the place of Reuben, supposing it to indicate the priestly
> office borne by the firstborn; but this is doubtful, and it was Judah
> to whom Jacob gave the right of primogeniture.

Also the remarks of the Cambridge commentary -

> **a coat of many colours** Rather, as R.V. marg., a long garment with sleeves. The familiar rendering “a coat of many colours,” derived from
> LXX χιτῶνα ποικίλον, Vulg. tunicam polymitam, is certainly incorrect.
> It is literally “a tunic of palms,” i.e. reaching to the palms of the
> hands and the soles of the feet, differing from an ordinary tunic by
> having sleeves, and by reaching to the feet. The same word is used in
> 2 Samuel 13:18 of a dress worn by a princess, where LXX χιτὼν καρπωτός
> and Lat. tunica talaris are correct. The rendering of the margin, of
> Pesh., Symm. (χειριδωτόν) and Aquila (χιτὼν ἀστραγάλων), if less
> picturesque, is more accurate.
>
> The unwise favouritism shewn by his father heightened the unpopularity
> of the boy.

Answer (score 2):

In Jewish culture, and Arabic as well - a long-sleeved robe signified nobility and rank ([SOURCE] - second paragraph[1](https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/culture/ancient-hebrew-clothing.htm), Gesenius as well).  Essentially every family had one, and whoever wore it was basically the favorite chosen by the father.  The Hebrew word pas can be translated as many colors or a long-sleeved robe.  The Septuagint favors long-sleeved robe. Ancient commentary such as Rashi, states it is both based on other passages in the Old Testament, such 2 Samuel 13:18 and Esther 1:6.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because he was the firstborn of Rachel who he loved.
2. Tanakh says he was born in his old age so he loved him more than the others.

That said why the colorful coat

1. He expressed his love by making (Maybe he made it himself) a coat for him with many colors.
2. These are said to be fine wool to express how special Joseph was to him.
3. There are some writings that Jacob knew that Jospeph will go through many trials like the colors in his coat
4. Some say these colors represented Royalty so Jacob might have believed that Joseph will one day be raised up to power (Maybe Royalty - 2nd to Pharoah) - In 2 Samuel 13:18, Tamar, King David’s daughter, wears an ornate robe of many colors, reserved for royalty.

Comment: The writings that state Joseph will face trials - I assume you mean the Midrash Aggadah?

Comment: Yes. Chabad commentary gives this as a likely meaning